# Proper way to use style attributes

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using DocumentApp.Attribute with mixed results. Here is an example:

```
var underline = {};
underline[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = true;
underline[DocumentApp.Attribute.WIDTH] = 100;
underline[DocumentApp.Attribute.MARGIN_LEFT] = 10;

doc.appendParagraph("Paragraph text").setAttributes(underline);
```

The paragraph is created, and underlined, but the other two attributes don't get applied.

Comment: What do you expect these two attributes to do to a paragraph?

Comment: I would like the paragraph to be indented 10 (px or pt - units don't really matter), be underlined, and I would like the underline to span the whole page width, kind of like you could do with an <h1> element in HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you will find that a paragraph cannot have either Margin or width attributes ... they apply to the page or document as a whole. You might get the effect that you wish by using the Indent set of attributes.
This begs the next question "how do you set page attributes?"

MARGIN-LEFT appears as an attribute of the Body section so getActiveSection().setAttributes(style)

I am not sure what width refers to but you can do a getAttributes for each element type to track it down PAGE-WIDTH is an attribute of Body Section again. Play around with this code ...

```
function myFunction() {
 var doc = DocumentApp.openById("1lqjkdfdsafgdsafsdaQI3kjtY");
var docele = doc.getActiveSection();
Logger.log(docele.getAttributes());
var para = doc.getParagraphs()[0];
var atts = para.getAttributes();
Logger.log(atts)
// Define a custom paragraph style.
var style = {};

style[DocumentApp.Attribute.WIDTH] = 100;
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.MARGIN_LEFT] = 200;
docele.setAttributes(style);
```

}

For me this gave body section attributes of `{UNDERLINE=null, MARGIN_BOTTOM=72.0, PAGE_HEIGHT=792.0, BOLD=null, BACKGROUND_COLOR=null, FONT_SIZE=null, FONT_FAMILY=null, STRIKETHROUGH=null, MARGIN_LEFT=10.0, PAGE_WIDTH=612.0, LINK_URL=null, ITALIC=null, MARGIN_RIGHT=72.0, MARGIN_TOP=72.0, FOREGROUND_COLOR=null}`

and paragraph attributes of `{UNDERLINE=null, INDENT_END=8.25, LEFT_TO_RIGHT=true, BOLD=null, BACKGROUND_COLOR=null, FONT_SIZE=12, FONT_FAMILY=Comic Sans MS, SPACING_BEFORE=null, SPACING_AFTER=null, STRIKETHROUGH=null, INDENT_START=0.0, LINE_SPACING=null, LINK_URL=null, ITALIC=null, INDENT_FIRST_LINE=0.0, HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT=null, HEADING=null, FOREGROUND_COLOR=null}`

This gives a clue to the alternative form for  setting of attributes
`docele.setAttributes({"FOREGROUND_COLOR":"#ff0000"})`

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I had to use this approach when styling elements within the document. For example, instead of MARGIN_LEFT, I used p.setIndentFirstLine(), and etc. I thought those attributes were global for all elements, so Thanks for differentiating that.